# como puedo hacer para no estar copiando la linea nuevamente más rapido?

Tags: java

Como puedo hacer para no copiar la misma linea de codigo rapidamente?

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres, ¿qué quieres conseguir? ¿Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y explicar un poco más?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Métodos, funcionan de la siguiente manera.
Primero, debes declarar un tipo de método para almacenar las lineas de código que sabes que estarás usando continuamente. Por ejemplo:

```
int Z=0;

Public void Metodo1(int X, int Y)
{
  Z= X+Y;
}
```

En tu case main:

```
Public Static void Main(String[]0)
{
   Metodo1(4,6);
   JOptionPane...("La suma es:"+Z);
   Metodo1(5,5);
   JOptionPane...("La suma es:"+Z);
   .
   .
   .
   Metodo1(10,10);
   JOptionPane...("La suma es:"+Z);
}
```

Este es solo una introducción a el conocimiento básico que deberás tener. Un método son lineas de código que se pueden mandar a llamar desde cualquier parte del digo sin necesidad de volverlo a escribir. Te recomiendo investigar [Java desde cero](https://javadesdecero.es/poo/metodos-con-ejemplos/)
y [Tipos de Metodos](https://www.arkaitzgarro.com/java/capitulo-14.html)
Aqui te dejo un [Ejemplo](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/04/metodos.html) mas claro de lo que te comente.

Espero haberte ayudado y respondido tu pregunta.

Comment: A mi me pareció claro lo que quiso dar a entender, se nota que apenas esta comenzando en el mundo de la programación. No importa si se cierra, me gusta apoyar y enseñar el camino a nuevos usuarios de la Programación. Si el chavo alcanza a leer mi respuesta que bueno, si no... ni modos. Saludos!